# ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

A question that a Stack Overflow user emailed to me:

> I have the below function:
>
> ```
> (defn partial-or-fill-at-test? [price]
>   (if (partial-or-fill-at? price) true (do (println "WRONG PRICE") false)))
> ```
>
> I get the below error when I use it:
>
> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
> ```
>
> I want to it to print something when the result of that predicate is false. Any help will do.

Comment: Cn you paste the code for `partial-or-fill-at`? Otherwise it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Comment: @DiegoBasch I emailed the person back and linked them to this question; only they have the code. @Andrews, if you need help finding the problem within `partial-or-fill-at?`, then please edit this question to include the code for that function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhere in your definition of `partial-or-fill-at?`. If I try a simple definition of `partial-or-fill-at?` as as function, everything works:

```
(defn partial-or-fill-at? [price] (> price 100))

(defn partial-or-fill-at-test? [price]
  (if (partial-or-fill-at? price) true (do (println "WRONG PRICE") false)))
```

```
user=> (partial-or-fill-at-test? 200)
true
user=> (partial-or-fill-at-test? 50)
WRONG PRICE
false
```

The error message `java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` means that somewhere, you have a Boolean (`true` or `false`) that is trying to used as an `IFn` (Clojure’s name for a function).

The `true` and `false` literals in your code are being used as values, not functions, so that is not the problem. The only place where a boolean could be used like a function is `partial-or-fill-at?`. If you defined it with a boolean value, using `def` instead of `defn`, you would get this error. For example, perhaps you accidentally wrote this:

```
; earlier in the code
(def price 500)

; …

(def partial-or-fill-at? (> price 100))
```

when you meant this:

```
(defn partial-or-fill-at? [price] (> price 100))
```

Inspect your definition of `partial-or-fill-at?` – also making sure that all parentheses balance and that the definition covers the section of code you expect it to – and figure out how to change its value from a boolean to a function.